# How do I run an individual test in Maven?

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

We're using Maven 3.0.3 and are using JUnit 4.8.1 ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We have this test file ...

```
./src/test/java/com/myco/clearing/common/xml/TextNodeTest.java
```

How can I run this individual test?  When I try

```
mvn -Dtest=TextNodeTest test
```

I get an error saying no tests were run.  I get the same error if I specify the entire package name to my test. ...

```
mvn clean -Dtest=com.myco.clearing.common.xml.TextNodeTest test
```

which produces the error message ...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project myco-productplus-web: No tests were executed!
(Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is the surefire configuration I'm using

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>gwt.args</name>
                        <value>-out "${webappDirectory}"</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <tomcat.port>${tomcat.servlet.port}</tomcat.port>
                    <project.artifactId>${project.artifactId}</project.artifactId>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Dave, did the downgrade to 2.11 work?

Answer (score 6):

The way to run a single test (method) in surefire is to do:

```
mvn test -Dtest=uk.co.farwell.AppTest#testSlow
```

Note the # instead of the space between the class name and the method name.

However, as @Andrew says, there is a bug in 2.12 ([SUREFIRE-827: Surefire 2.12 cannot run a single test, regression from 2.11](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-827)), but it works in 2.11.

<s>The above bug is still open (as of 24.02.2012), but actually works for me using 2.13-SNAPSHOT.</s>

EDIT: This is now marked as fixed in 2.12.1.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a bug in 2.12 version - [SUREFIRE-827](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-827). Try downgrading to 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others say, it's a bug in Surefire and **it's fixed since version 2.11.1**.